# 502 Bad gateway when using Transfer encoding Python

Tags: python, sockets, http, transfer-encoding, bad-gateway

I'm trying to build a barebones HTTP/1.1 client using just sockets. Whenever i try to use Transfer-encoding: chuncked, the code give me following status:502 Bad Gateway.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("socket successfully created.")
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
s.connect((host_ip,80))
op = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nTransfer-encoding: chunked\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
s.sendall(op.encode('utf-8'))
print(s.recv(500000))
s.close()
```

This is giving me following o/p:

```
socket successfully created.
b'HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer\r\nContent-Length: 1613\r\nDate: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 00:42:04 GMT\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s all we know.</ins>\n'
```

If I remove the 'Transfer-encoding: chunked' header, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you are using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the first place. You are doing a GET request which means that there is no request body, i.e. no request content. And if there is no content the non-existing content can not be encoded.

Apart from that: chunked Transfer-Encoding is only defined with HTTP/1.1 but not with HTTP/1.0. If the server supports only HTTP/1.0 it will not understand what you mean. And, even many system which claim to support HTTP/1.1 does not understand Transfer-Encoding within a request because this is seldom used, i.e. browsers don't use it. Thus you can only use chunked Transfer-Encoding if you can be sure that the server itself and any middleboxes in between (i.e. firewall, load balancer, reverse proxy...) will support it.